# Need help "translating" an excel formula to an SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, logic, operators

How do I translate a nested If() Excel formula to SSRS language?

I have not attempted yet, don't know how to even start. I'm a newbie in ssrs.
the Excel formula is as follows:

```
=IF(A1>B1,"NO TEST",(IF(C1="4567","NEW","OLD")))
```

NOTE:  A and B are datetime values, C is data type char(6) {either "OK" or "4567"}.  B can be NULL.

What I want to accomplish is to show in a textbox in my report either "NO TEST", "NEW" or "OLD".

Answer (score 0):

Similar like in Excel. `4567` for a number and `"4567"` for a string:

```
=IFF(CDate(Fields!A1.Value) > IFF(IsDate(Fields!B1.Value),  Fields!B1.Value, "01.01.1900"), "No Test", IFF(Fields!C1.Value = "4567", "New", "Old"))
```

If `B1` can be null you have to filter it away or you check for `Null`, because the`CDate()` function will throw an error with `Null`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually tried something "similar" to your response while I waited for someone to answer with the same results. It went like this:  
=IIF(Fields!A1.Value>Fields!B1.Value,"NO TESTING REQD",(IIF(Fields!C1.Value="4567  ","NEW","OLD")))". I did change it to your recommendation though.  It's interesting.

Comment: So I have a follow up question regarding the NULL value.  So the SQL query is sending "NULL" over to SSRS.  In SSRS the field is empty for B1, so the calculation of IIF A1>B1 is always true because a value is greater than nothing.  So I've been looking into the IsNothing function.  I am thinking to precede the above expression with something like if B1 is nothing then B1="12/31/2050" so the comparison of A1>B1 is always false (well, until 12/31/2050) and the rest of the logic proceeds without error.